# patch request to microsoft graph api for planner task does not return the updated task in the response

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner

According to the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/planner_order_hint_format) on updating order hints in planner.

> The client can obtain the values immediate if return=representation preference is specified in the PATCH requests.

I've tried putting this in the header, and as a query parameter, but I still only get back a 204 response.
Where in the `PATCH` request, does the `return=representation` go ?

Comment: Did you want to update a planner task and want to get the updated task after patching request?

Comment: I can get the updated planner task with a second call to the API. I wanted to be more efficient than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [graph sdk team](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/306) enlightened me.
The header Prefer:return=representation is what needs to be set.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you can see in the [docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/planner_order_hint_format):

> Important: APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are in
>   preview and are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production
>   applications is not supported.

The API is still in development. So the documentation may update too.

You can submit an issue to the [Github issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues) list first. Meanwhile vote up the existing request or submit a new one in the [UserVoice](https://planner.uservoice.com/forums/330525-microsoft-planner-feedback-forum?query=representation%20)

Comment: I was originally hitting the V1.0 endpoint. I just tried the beta endpoint but got the same result. Both endpoints allow the order hints to be updated per the documentation (which is under the beta url as you point out!). So I think it fair to assume that the whole document therefore applies to V1 endpoint. I'll post a github issue. I did not do that first, expecting to be told to post something on SO first !